# easiest way to play mp3 from storage

Tags: java, android

I'm a newbie. I just want to play mp3 in my app.
I've read the documentation and I browsed through many websites including this one.
The steps should be

```
MediaPlayer.setDataSource(String) or (context, Uri)
.prepare();
.start();
```

My file is in `/storage/emulated/0/New Folder/ztz3.mp3` ..
if i use `External.getExternalDirectory().getPath()` the result is `/storage/emulated/0/`

but it just won't play.
I've browsed many sites.. trying many things but it just didn't work.
I've used permission to read external storage.

and the sites I'm browsing has too many different answers which only confused me more.
some use AudioManager.STREAM.. some use MediaPlayer.create.
and I followed that too.. but it just won't play.

---

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button buttonPlay;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button buttonPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPlay);

    //        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+
    //                "/New Folder/ztz_3_adding.mp3";
    //        String filePath = "/storage/emulated/0/New Folder/ztz_3_adding.mp3";
        Log.e("Dir", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString());
        Log.e("Directory", Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());

        mediaPlayer = new  MediaPlayer();
        //mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

        try {
            // mediaPlayer.setDataSource("/storage/emulated/0/New Folder/ztz_3_adding.mp3");
            // mediaPlayer.setDataSource("file://storage/emulated/0/New Folder/ztz_3_adding.mp3");
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(getApplicationContext(),
                    Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+
                            "/New Folder/ztz_3_adding.mp3"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            //mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        buttonPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mediaPlayer.start();

            }
        });


    }
}
```

I think the problem is in the prepare() method.. but I don't know how to fix it.
I've read and tried a site that said to use static MediaPlayer.create or something.

I just want a simple media player that use a string value that I can change anytime to play mp3 files based on the layout.

thanks for the help before...

---

the log...

> 02-25 22:10:08.546 17345-17345/com.echo.tesmediaplayer E/Dir:
>   /storage/emulated/0 02-25 22:10:08.548
>   17345-17345/com.echo.tesmediaplayer E/Directory: /storage/emulated/0
>   02-25 22:10:08.563 17345-17345/? E/MediaPlayer: prepareAsync called in
>   state 1 02-25 22:10:08.564 17345-17345/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.echo.tesmediaplayer, PID: 17345 
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.echo.tesmediaplayer/com.echo.tesmediaplayer.MainActivity}:java.lang.IllegalStateException
>
> at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2440)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500)at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163)at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585) at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730)
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)
>
> Caused by: java.lang.**IllegalStateExceptionat**
>   android.media.MediaPlayer._prepare(Native Method) at
>   android.media.MediaPlayer.prepare(MediaPlayer.java:1158) at
>   com.echo.tesmediaplayer.MainActivity.onCreate(**MainActivity.java:48**)
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6279) at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2393)
>   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2500) 
>   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:163)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362) 
>   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)  at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5585)  at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)  at
>   .android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:730) 
>   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:620)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the permissions set correctly?
You need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

See: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#manifest

Comment: I only use the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE..

but I've add the other two and the error is still the same.

Comment: Strange, your code works fine on my device. (Android 5.0). Try this:
`final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"..."));`
With this there is no need to call the prepare method whatsoever. You just need to call `mp.start();` _after_ buffering is completed!
Hope it will work now.

Comment: I tried it ..
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(‌​) + "/New Folder/ztz_3_adding.mp3"));

but I got error illegal character in the .getPath()

my code works fine on your phone ? it's weird.

Comment: I tried with my other phone (Evercross A74A) and it works. Strange in my LG X Power it doesn't work.
Much appreciated for the help.